# Safari will not load html5 audio tag

Tags: html, audio, safari

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
hello world
<audio controls autoplay>
<source src="Strobe.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
<source src="Strobe.wav" type="audio/x-wav"/>
<source src="Strobe.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
</audio>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

This will load fine in Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera but not Safari.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your head tag is not closed properly. `body` must come *after* the head tag.

Comment: Oh man I forgot about this question lol. This was back when I was the noob of noobs. Good spot sir.